# How can I duplicate a "cancel" button using a toolbar

Tags: xpages

I am using the toolbar control and that has several actions on it to allow the user to switch document modes, save, return to the view, etc.

I want to add a cancel button to allow the user to cancel their edits and switch them back to read mode.

Since the same event is shared by all these actions (I am using simple actions in computed action groups) I can't check off the "Do not validate or update data".  If I do a `context.redirectToPage("newpage.xsp")` that will cause validation to happen.

I want to be able "cancel" the validation and then perform some action like switch to read mode or to another XPage.  Any suggestions?

I guess I need a `context.DontSave()` method...Is there a method I can use to disable the validation/updating when submitting?

Thanks,

Howard

Answer (score 0):

You can create a standalone cancel button that discards changes and reloads the current page. In the example below I have not taken into account that the current page can contain parameters such as editDocument, documentId etc.

```
<xp:button id="cancel" value="Cancel" rendered="#{javascript:document.isEditable()}">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete" immediate="true" save="false" id="eventHandler1">
        <xp:this.action>
            <xp:actionGroup>
                <xp:openPage name="#{javascript:view.getPageName()}"></xp:openPage>
            </xp:actionGroup>
        </xp:this.action></xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Comment: use context.getUrl() instead of view.getPageName() and you will get full url with params

Comment: thanks, but, can't use a button, I was using the toolbar control which just has one event, onItemClick for all the menu options.  So, I can't set the immediate property since the other options on the toolbar won't work...it would have to be a solution in the SSJS code that runs in the onItemClick to somehow note that the validation shouldn't happen.

Comment: My idea was that you add this button next to your toolbar buttons (since you asked for a way to add a cancel button)

Comment: No, it has to be in the toolbar, I did work up one solution, in CSJS I test to see if the user clicked the cancel and if so, I just load a new url in the browser using location.href and then return false so it never gets to the server side JS part. Kind of a kludge.  thanks for your help!